# How can i merge(make common) validation criteria for spring boot and angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, validation, angular-validation, spring-validator

Right now i am implementing validation in spring boot and angular separately
it's working fine
but,
 when my validation criteria changes, need to make change at both side and redeploy both
can we have any solution where, we change at one place and will be applicable at both sides ?
Java code

```
@NotBlank(message = "Address is required.")
@Size(max = 300, message = "Allowed upto 300 characters for address.")
private String address;
```

Angular code
TS file

```
'address': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
```

HTML file

```
<textarea
     [maxlength]="utilsService.validationService.MAX_300"
     [formControl]="registrationForm.controls['address']">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

We have solved this task for simple validation rules, that validate single fields and are investivating on a solution for more complex situations.

Our solution sends all validation rules from bean validation (using reflection) as meta data payload via json to the client, if  - and only if - the client requests this via http header. Normally you only have to send the validation rules once.

On client side with JavaScript we interpret these rules and do the validation.

Some work at the start, but pays out in the long run.

Complex validation rules that bind several fields together are more cumbersome to implement. Expression languages like SpEL od UEL seem quite promising. Unfortunately there are hardly any implementations, that run the identical EL on both sides.

On of these implementations is [spel2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spel2js), but it is some days old and apparently not longer supported actively.

A further approach is to use JavaScript directly on server side. Seems a little odd to define validation rules for Java in JavaScript, but it's much easier to run JavaScript directly on client side that many other solutions. We're investigation on this approach right now.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that UI and API validation may not necessarily remain same always.

Anyways, two approach which I can think as of now -

1. You can write a validation service, pass entire json payload to the valdiation endpoint. You can call it from UI and Backend both and returns you the response either success or validation failure with detail.
2. User some specification document, JSON/YML which can be used to validate the request against. See below links where it shows how to validate JSON request based on open-api specs. Spring boot backend and angular UI can have same spec file to validate against and then you commit this to your repo, to be used by both front-end and Back-end.

https://github.com/kogosoftwarellc/open-api/tree/master/packages/openapi-schema-validator

https://springframework.guru/using-swagger-request-validator-to-validate-spring-cloud-contracts/

https://openapi.tools/